# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'createElement' can't find the solution

Tags: jquery, wordpress, message, createelement

I'm getting an Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'createElement' Error message and I have no idea how to fix this.  This projects deadline is tomorrow and I can't figure it out.  Please help me if you can, the preview link is [www.alexcoven.com/clothing](http://www.alexcoven.com/clothing) thanks in advance!
-Alex

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Please advice us on What event you are getting this error either on page load ?? or somewhere else